# Angular APP_INITIALIZER prevents feature modules from building

Tags: angular

I'm using the `APP_INITIALIZER` in my Angular app to load configuration when my app bootstraps. It technically works; the configuration is loaded and the app.module seems to build properly, but none of the feature modules are built and thus are unusable. Here's the output of `ng build` with the `APP_INITIALIZER`:

[image]

And here is the output without `APP_INITIALIZER`:

[image]

Here's the code that is called in the `APP_INITIALIZER` factory:

```
// in app.module.ts
function initConfig(configService: AppConfigService) {
    return () => configService.loadConfig();
}

// in app-config.service.ts
public loadConfig() {
    return this._http.get('./assets/app-config/config.json')
        .toPromise()
        .then((config: any) => {
            this.config = config;
            this.configSubject$.next(this.config);
        })
}
```

So as you can see, the factory returns a promise, it loads the configuration, etc., but something happens that prevents it from building the feature modules. Am I missing something in the factory that is preventing this from loading the feature module?

### Edit

As a test, I just returned true immediately in the initLoad factory function, and the same thing happened where the feature modules are not built.

### Edit 2

After a little more digging and looking at this, I believe the more accurate statement is that lazy loaded modules are the ones that are not being built. If a feature module is not lazy loaded, it seems to continue to be built and work as expected.

[Here's a GitHub repo](https://github.com/plambhsa/demo-app-initializer) with a demo app where a module is set up to lazy load. If you comment out the `providers` array in the `AppModule`, and run `ng build`, you'll see a line about the lazy loaded module being built, right under the `main` chunk. Then, re-add the providers array and run `ng build`, and only the `main` chunk is there.

Comment: Is it possible to create a minimal reproducible example in github repository?

Comment: why you write this.configSubject$.next? At first you have nothing that subscribe to this subject. If you want to get some variable of your data in one component you can (if your component has constructor(configService:ConfigService) ) in ngOnInit using directy configService.config.variable

Comment: The subject is there because some services load before the configuration is loaded. I was under the impression at first that this was supposed to run and finish before anything else started, but I found that that is not the case. If I didn't have some services subscribe to that subject, the configuration object is undefined.

Comment: @yurzui I've added an edit (edit 2) with a little more description of some research I've done over the weekend and a GitHub repo that you can clone to see what's going on.

Comment: Thank you for the demo. Try adding `export` to your `initConfig` function so it should be `export function initLoad() {...}`

Comment: @yurzui holy cow, thanks so much! That worked! Can you please add this as an answer so I can accept it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Seems don't exporting `initConfig` function breaks dependencies resolution algorithm.

So simply export it:

```
export function initLoad() {...}
```